# Android Phone EditText not updating the display on the device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-edittext

I've got a small Android app that I am developing and I have an `EditText` element which does not like to display it's contents while the keyboard is on the screeen.

For example I touch the editTextbox and it brings up the keyboard, pressing a letter, say `a` displays `a` in the textbox, but after that no new text shows up so the user is essentially typing blind from that point on.

This only happens on the device and not in the emulator. Vodafone 845 if it makes any difference.

The code I am using for the EditText is this.

```
 <EditText 
 android:id="@+id/EditAddress"
 android:layout_width="200px"
 android:singleLine="True"
 android:hint="Address or Landmark"/>
```

I did have a OnKeyListener and an OnClickListener, but removing them from the code makes no changes to the behaviour. The EditText is also inside of a TableLayout which is inside of another TableLayout. This is the only EditText that is behaving badly on the device. (I have not coded any others in the application. But might add some just to find out whats wrong.

EDIT: Ok, it seems to be caused if the keyboard obscures the location of the original editbox such that the view has to scroll down so the editbox will not be covered by the software keyboard. For now I can rearrange my page so the edit box is at the top. But this is a bit of a hacky solution. Anyone know what causes this and/or how to fix it.

Comment: Are you using the stock keyboard? I have a similar problem on my Android device with a custom keyboard, where sometimes I have to kill the keyboard for the letters to show up.

Comment: I am using the default onscreen keyboard that comes with the device, set to qwerty mode. The blinking line indicator | also doesn't blink, if that helps.

Comment: Is the problem specific to your EditText, or does it occur in other apps? What settings, listeners, etc do you have on your EditText?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give it a layout_height as well. Even if it is wrap_content or the like.